# Extract wrong paragraph direction in Word using Apache POI library

Tags: apache-poi

I need to extract the paragraph directions in Word documents (both .doc and .docx).

- For .doc documents, I use **`paragraph.cloneProperties().getFBiDi`** to get the directional information for paragraphs.
- For .docx documents, I use **`paragraph.getCTP != null && paragraph.getCTP.isSetPPr && paragraph.getCTP.getPPr.isSetBidi`**.

When HWPFDocument or XWPFDocument reads Arabic/Hebrew documents, I would expect that getFBiDi/isSetBiDi returns TRUE for the RTL paragraphs. However, it returns FALSE that represents "LTR" direction for some documents [see the example](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1vJzpmu7KAhXCJCYKHYznCdcQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wgig.org%2Fdocs%2FWGIGReport-Arabic.doc&usg=AFQjCNEdp9xHv9lpQC3LmZNHhLnCuDakbQ&sig2=OZRni_GsfkJE4HyrYBkf_A&bvm=bv.113943164,d.eWE).

Did I use the wrong API to get the paragraph directions?

Comment: This was also reported simultaneously at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58993 and https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58992

Answer (score 0):

Use below lines to set direction:

```
    if ( par.getCTP().getPPr()==null ) {
        par.getCTP().addNewPPr();
    }
    if ( par.getCTP().getPPr().getBidi()==null ) {
        par.getCTP().getPPr().addNewBidi();
    }
    par.getCTP().getPPr().getBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON); //or STOnOff.OFF
```

Comment: With code,Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue